# SED delete comments but leave specific negated comment strings

Tags: sed, comments, negation

I'm trying to delete comments from file but what's important I want to leave specific strings:

```
## Something
# START
# END
```

These has to stay with rest not commented lines and I want to remove rest with "d" - this is important. I don't want to use print negation or other tricks because this sed command also process another things later with additional "-e".

Here is sample file:

```
# START
group1: user1@domain.com, user2@domain.com, user3@domain.com
group2: user3@domain.com, user4@domain.com

# S
#STAR
# start
# star
# comment is here
## Owner1
group3: user1@domain.com, user3@domain.com

## Owner2
group4: user4@domain.com, user3@domain.com

group3: user2@domain.com, user3@domain.com

# END

group5: user4@domain.com
alias1: user6@domain.com
```

I tried to use command like:

```
sed -e '/^#[^#]/d' sample.file
```

Which remove each line starting with "#" and next character is NOT "#" so it leaves "##" lines but how to manage removing rest without loosing # START and # END lines?

I need to do this in same command without pipes, "!p" or "p" versions it has to be this "d" modified version.
Tried things like:

```
sed -e '/^#[^#][^S][^T][^A][^R][^T]/d'
```

or

```
sed -e '/^#[^#]\([^S][^T][^A][^R][^T]\|[^E][^N][^D]\)/d'
```

but nothing is working the way I want.
I'm not sure if this is possible this way.

Expected output:

```
# START
group1: user1@domain.com, user2@domain.com, user3@domain.com
group2: user3@domain.com, user4@domain.com

## Owner1
group3: user1@domain.com, user3@domain.com

## Owner2
group4: user4@domain.com, user3@domain.com

group3: user2@domain.com, user3@domain.com

# END

group5: user4@domain.com
alias1: user6@domain.com
```

Greetings & thanks for help :)

Comment: Please give more context of the code to demonstrate the restrictions you impose. I.e. show some dummy "additional -e".

Comment: Hoe about using awk/gawk instead of sed? It might be a tad easier and more readable to fulfill your criteria that way.

Comment: Maybe show some versions of your coding attempts which basically do as required but file your side requirements. Ideally show what does not work with them because of that.

Comment: I've overseen the 'no p'-requierement. Can you explain what is problematic with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -E '/^##|^# START|^# END/bskip; /^#/d; :skip' file
```

#### Example

```
$ sed -E '/^##|^# START|^# END/bskip; /^#/d; :skip' file
# START
group1: user1@domain.com, user2@domain.com, user3@domain.com
group2: user3@domain.com, user4@domain.com

## Owner1
group3: user1@domain.com, user3@domain.com

## Owner2
group4: user4@domain.com, user3@domain.com

group3: user2@domain.com, user3@domain.com

# END

group5: user4@domain.com
alias1: user6@domain.com
```

#### How it works

- `/^##|^# START|^# END/bskip`

  For any line that matches  `^##` or `^# START` or `^# END`, we branch to the label `skip`.
- `/^#/d`

  For all other lines that start with `#`, we delete.
- `:skip`

  This defines the label `skip`.

#### BSD/macOS

The above was tested with GNU sed.  For BSD/macOS sed, try:

```
sed -E -e '/^##|^# START|^# END/bskip' -e '/^#/d' -e ':skip' file
```

Comment: Hi, seems that's working but tell me this -E this seems different than -e and maybe won't be supported on all linux systems? I guess this is only for more clean "OR" = "|"? Seems this is working too: sed -e '/^##\|^# START\|^# END/bskip; /^#/d; :skip'. Thanks!

Comment: @mike Yes, that is exactly right: `-E` invokes Extended Regular Expressions which, in our case, allows `|` in place of `\|`.   And, yes, your version without `-E` will work just as well.

Comment: i think that `-r` does the job on linux. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  `-r` will work with both modern and ancient GNU sed.  However, POSIX appears to have settled on `-E` rather than `-r` for extended regular expressions.  Consequently, all modern versions of GNU sed, also accept `-E` to enable extended regexes.  On BSD/macOS, only `-E` is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This is more verbose than John1024s answer, but works too:

```
sed -r 's/# ((START)|(END)).*/## \1/;/^#[^#].*/d;s/## ((START)|(END))/# \1/;' sample.conf
```

Transfer the # START/END comment to the protected ## format, then, do the transformation, then transform it to # START/END back.

First I've overseen the 'no-/p'-requierement, then the obvious solution is:

```
sed -r '/# (START)|(END).*/p;/^#[^#].*/d' sample.conf
```

Instead of deleting a complicated delete-pattern /d, you can use a simple print-pattern /p.

Note that `[^S][^T][^A][^R][^T]` would match "`END`" (with 2 trailing spaces - maybe unlikely, but if another 3- or 5-letter exception needs treatment, it gets ugly, if it isn't alread.